# Is it possible to add a page to every user's watch list? (Mediawiki)

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions

I would like to create a general discussion page for my small wiki (Mediawiki Version 1.39.1). It would be best if every user is notified if something is written on the page. For this I have installed the extension Echo. As far as I know, the page must also be on the watch list in order to get notifications. It would be cumbersome to tell each user to add the page to the watch list. So how can I put the page on the watch list by default (ideally with opt out)?

All informations about my wiki: https://academia.la/wiki/Special:Version

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: I don't know if there is an existing extension or script to accomplish this. Do you have SSH access to the server? You could [write your own maintenance script](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Writing_maintenance_scripts), perhaps using [purgeExpiredWatchlistItems.php](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/source/mediawiki/browse/master/maintenance/purgeExpiredWatchlistItems.php) as an example along with the [WatchedItemStore::addWatch](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classWatchedItemStore.html#a46dee2e7a1515fc10a2d2e30801b280e) method.

Comment: @ChrisYungmann Yes, I do have access, but unfortunately I lack the knowledge to write something like that.